# NSURL Array Error in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, audio, nsurl

So I'm trying to create a variable that I can use to pick a random sound from an NSURL array I created. This is the array, which is the line that causes the error:

```
var levelOneSounds = 
    [
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Barn", ofType: "mp3")!),
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chicken", ofType: "mp3")!),
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Birds", ofType: "mp3")!),
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Camera", ofType: "mp3")!), NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Cat", ofType: "mp3")!), 
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Crickets", ofType: "mp3")!),
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Glass", ofType: "mp3")!),
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Siren", ofType: "mp3")!), NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Slap", ofType: "mp3")!),
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Snoring", ofType: "mp3")!),
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Toilet Flushing", ofType: "mp3")!),
        NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Wolves Howling", ofType: "mp3")!)
    ]
```

Obviously, all of these are mp3 files that I stored in the Supporting Files folder. I also created the audio player here:

```
var levelOneAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Here is my `viewDidLoad()` method where I create the random sound variable and play that sound:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    var randomSound = levelOneSounds[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(levelOneSounds.count)))]

    levelOneAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: randomSound, error: nil)
    levelOneAudioPlayer.play()
}
```

However whenever I run this and go into this view controller, I get the following error at the array:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode = 0 x 0)

What can I do to fix this so the random sound is played? I'm new to programming, so I apologize if I made an obvious mistake. Thanks!

Here is a link to the photo of the resource folder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj3yG.png

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: The array init causes the error? Have you checkt if NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource aint nil?

Comment: The first line of code in the chat: var levelOneSounds @MustangXY

Comment: I watched a video tutorial for how to add sounds into the project and I basically copied what was done in the video except I put the sounds into an array instead of just one sound into a single variable, so I'm not really sure. Like I said, I'm new to programming @Neo

Comment: The crash occurs because one of the (optional) URLs is unwrapped while being `nil`. Check the spelling of the file names, I guess there is a typo or a file is missing

Comment: There are no missing files and there are no typos, but I when I put the files in earlier I did change the names of them to match with the code I wrote. Could this have affected it? @vadian

Comment: The file names must exactly be the same as those of the physical files in the resources folder.

Comment: Click on the link to the picture of the resource folder, just so we can figure out that we are on the same page @vadian

Comment: The problem is the physical subfolder `Level 1`. I posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because your sounds are located in a subfolder of the resources folder.

The basic function `pathForResource:ofType:` does not consider subfolders.

From the documentation:

> The method first looks for a matching resource file in the non-localized resource directory of the specified bundle. If a matching resource file is not found, it then looks in the top level of an available language-specific .lproj folder. (The search order for the language-specific folders corresponds to the user’s preferences.) **It does not recurse through other subfolders at any of these locations**.

You have to use this function

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Barn", ofType: "mp3", inDirectory:"Level 1")
```

or this much more effective function to get all URLs with one line

```
let levelOneSounds = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLsForResourcesWithExtension("mp3", subdirectory:"Level 1")
```

Comment: Ok thanks this helped so much with the first error, but just one more question: now, I get this error at the line `levelOneAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: randomSound, error: nil)` - is there anything you have an idea of what I can do to fix this or should I create a create a new question on this topic? Thanks! @vadian

Comment: Check the code in the original question for reference @vadian

Comment: where is `levelOneSounds` declared?

Comment: `levelOneSounds` is declared right above `class SoundGameViewController: UIViewController {`. The statement `levelOneAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: randomSound, error: nil)` is declared in the `viewDidLoad()` method @vadian

Comment: It's probably too soon and outside the class. Write a declaration line `var levelOneSounds : [NSURL]!` **inside** the class but outside any function and `levelOneSounds = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLsForResourcesWithExtension("mp3", subdirectory:"Level 1")` in `viewDidLoad` before creating the random sound

Comment: I tried this, but then I get an error on the line: `levelOneSounds = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLsForResourcesWithExtension("mp3", subdirectory:"Level 1")` saying `Cannot assign a value of type [AnyObject]? to a value of type [NSURL]!` @vadian

Comment: force downcast the array since you certainly know it's an array of `NSURL`:  `levelOneSounds = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLsForResourcesWithExtension("mp3", subdirectory:"Level 1") as! [NSURL]`

Comment: That did help with the error on that line, but I am still experiencing an error on the line in the `viewDidLoad` method `levelOneAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: randomSound, error: nil)`. I'm so sorry this is taking so long, thanks for all your patience. @vadian

Comment: declare the `AudioPlayer` variable also inside the class/outside any function this way `var levelOneAudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!` and pass an `NSError` instance to the error parameter for catching the error

Comment: However, sometimes it actually works and I don't receive that error, but other times I do @vadian

Comment: How should I pass the NSError instance to the error parameter? Yes, I'm new to programming @vadian

Comment: `var error : NSError?`   `levelOneAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: randomSound, error: &error)`  `if error != nil { println(error!) }`

Comment: I added all of that but now I am getting the error on the line I told the audio to play in the `viewDidLoad()` method: `levelOneAudioPlayer.play()`. However sometimes I don't get this error, but I do not hear the sound. As you can see, I'm trying to play the sound once the new view has loaded @vadian - Once again, thanks for all the patience.